# RxJs: getting which of the object keys changed in sequence filtered via distinctUntilChanged() without keeping external state

Tags: javascript, typescript, rxjs, observable

Let **`orders$`** is RxJs sequence of objects as shown below. We listen for changes with **`distinctUntilChanged()`** and take different actions based on which key changed. Can we tell inside the **`tap()`** which object key actually changed, without keeping track of the previous change via the external **`previousItem`** variable ?

Example:

```
let orders$ = of([
  { main: 'pizza', drink: 'cola', id: 0},
  { main: 'pizza', drink: 'cola', id: 1},
    ...
  { main: 'pizza', drink: 'cola', id: 3332},
  { main: 'pizza', drink: 'fanta', id: 3333},    // <-- drink changes
]); 

let previousItem = null;

orders$.pipe(
  distinctUntilChanged((o0, o1) => o0.main === o1.main || o0.drink === o1.drink),
  tap(item => {

      /* Which value actually changed -'main' or 'drink' ?! */

      if (previousItem && previousItem.main !== item.main) {
        doSthForMainChanged();
      }

      doSthForDrinkChanged();
      previousItem = item;        // <-- ... so that not to tweak via external state

  })).subscribe();
```

Comment: Did you try pairwise operator [https://rxjs.dev/api/operators/pairwise; https://www.learnrxjs.io/operators/combination/pairwise.html]?

Answer (score 2):

I could suggest to do it with `scan`:

```
source$.pipe(
  scan((last: any, item: any) => {
    let changes: any = {}
    last.main !== item.main ? changes.main = true : false
    last.drink !== item.drink ? changes.drink = true : false
    return {item, changes}
  }, {}),
  tap(({item, changes}) => {
    if (changes.main) {
      doSthForMainChanged();
    }
    if (changes.drink) {
      doSthForDrinkChanged();
    }    
  })
)
```

and you can also add distinctUntilChanged at the end if needed

Answer (score 1):

You can split the observable into two streams for each type of change, and then use map to track those changes.

```
   const main$ = orders$.pipe(
        distinctUntilChanged((o0, o1) => o0.main === o1.main),
        map(value => ({changed:'main', value}))
   );

   const drink$ = orders$.pipe(
        distinctUntilChanged((o0, o1) => o0.drink === o1.drink),
        map(value => ({changed:'drink', value}))
   );

   merge(main$, drink$).pipe(
       tap(item => {
          if (item.changed === 'main') {
              doSthForMainChanged();
          } else if(item.changed === 'drink') {
              doSthForDrinkChanged();
          }
   })).subscribe();
```

The only side effect of the above is that the tap will be executed twice if both main and drink change for a single emitted value. I don't know if this is a problem for your business logic or not.